# pg_ctl: could not start server

Tags: redhat, postgresql, putty, database-connection, start

I am trying to start the PostgreSQL server installed on a remote Redhat server(RHEL 6.7 x86_64) through putty.

The command that I used to start the server is `/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.5 start`
But it is showing the following error:

[image: postgresql error]

This is the content of **/pg_log/startup.log** file:

[image: /pg_log/startup.log]

Here is the link for the content of **postgresql.conf** file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Yw9pzgnSgTTTBKaWxwWXUtNTg/view?usp=sharing

I checked the postgresql.conf file but could not find any error.
Can anybody help me resolve this issue?

**Edit:**
posting the output of **"locale"** command as asked by @Michael Hampton

[image: locale_output]

Comment: What language was the system installed with? Post the output of the `locale` command.

Comment: @ Michael Hampton....I have posted the output of locale command

Comment: Wow, how did you get the system into this state? What did Red Hat say when you opened a case with them?

Comment: @ Michael Hampton....I really don' know how the system got into this state...is there something wrong in it??

Comment: What did Red Hat say when you opened a case with them?

Comment: @Michael Hampton...sorry, but I am not getting what are you saying??

Comment: For the third time, you should contact Red Hat and open a case. Then once the case is finished, you should come back here and tell us what the resolution was.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this article and try suggested fixes 
http://blog.earth-works.com/2014/02/10/fixing-lc-locale-issues-in-centos-and-rhel/

That guy has the same output of `locale` command as yours.

Comment: There is no `dpkg-reconfigure` on a RHEL system.

Comment: @Stefan Mihajlovic....yes, Michael Hampton is right...dpkg-reconfigure not working on RHEL system...

Comment: You are right guys, for a moment I forgot it is RHEL